# how to mention user in dms

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

currently my bot mentions in dm like this:
[@<@630033944229969920> (click for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgniG.png)

Is there a way to mention the user or say their name but not their id?
I'm using this code:

```
.setTitle(`@${member} welcome to Premium Studios!`)
```

Comment: You cannot mention in embed titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use mentions of any kind in your Embed Title. You can, however, use one of the following methods to display the name of a `GuildMember`:

```
member.displayName //outputs either the nickname or username of a member
member.user.username //outputs the username of a member
member.user.tag //outputs the username and discriminator of a member
```